# What would happen if a person had the right side of their body totally removed (including the brain)?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

[image]

What would happen (in reality or theoretically) if the entire right side of a human's body was removed?

Could they live (aside from all the probable infections and such)?

I would guess that humans can live without part of the liver or brain.

The left brain controls the right side of the body.

What do you think (or know) will happen?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: in the odd chance that the person survives, (s)he would be totally immobile as the right half of brain controls the left half of the body and vice-versa. The only part of the body that the person can control would be the upper half of face which is supplied by both halves of the brain!

Comment: This reminds me of a joke: Q. "What happens if a person has the *left* side of the body totally removed?"  A. "I think they'd be alright!"

Answer (score 5):

They would die.

Let's imagine that we perfectly cut a person down the middle. That would mean cutting the spinal cord in half, probably damaging the tissue so much that the remaining half wouldn't work well. The liver would be gone. The intestines and bladder would just be open. The heart would have to be adjusted to the left. The surgery would probably cause so much blood loss that they wouldn't even survive to die of other organ failure.

And you already alluded to the mismatch between what side of the brain controls what side of the body, so if you kept the pseudocorpse "alive" on an IV, heart lung machine, and hemodialysis, they'd probably still be paralyzed.

Answer (score 4):

We humans are not perfectly symmetrical. Some organs exist only on one side of the body which are critical for life.That said you can however live without half your brain (if you call that state living) and some other organs also have distributed function over thier surface.